# Font awesome custom icons , can you load them using css psuedo?

Tags: font-awesome

i'm using font awesome 6.4 pro , i have download the libray downloaded and hosted on my server.

Using the custom icons with html they all show fine , but i can not figure out how to use the custom icons with css before and after , has anyone had any success doing this ?

```
<i class="fa-kit fa-football2-1"></i>

Unicode: e040
```

when i try to use the provided unicode , it shows another normal icon that has same unicode as my custom one does

Answer (score 0):

by some luck i just figured out how to use custom icons in css before and after , you have to include "font-family: Font Awesome Kit;" as part of the css for the before or after